# Corrupt Transaction Log on database

Tags: sql-server, replication, disaster-recovery

I have reason to believe the transaction log file on my database is corrupt.

This database is involved in transaction based replication (both subscription and publishing), and I'm unable to start its log reader agent with an error message which cites "Operating System Error 23".

I essentially just want to do what it takes to be able to restart the log reader agent, and my best idea so far is to somehow clear the log file, detach from it and reattach to a new log file. I'm not sure what the data loss implications of this would be though. Is this the best solution or is there a better way to deal with a corrupt log file? It is not a production database so avoiding data loss is not absolutely necessary (though preferable). There are no backups.

Comment: Are you sure your DB log file is corrupt? Can you run DBCC CHECKDB with NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS on the database and post its output? Also, can you please post the full error message you are getting in log reader agent?

Comment: The error is 'Operating system error 23(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105) on file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MYSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MY_DATABASE.ldf" during CheckLogBlockReadComplete.' Regarding the DBCC CHECKDB command, is this a very resource-intensive process as there is other important stuff going on on this server? Thanks

Comment: What is the current state of database? Is it online? Yes, CHECKDB is a resource intensive process. It depends on the DB size and amount of corruption it finds.

Comment: It is online but could be temporarily taken offline if need be. The log file is around 70gb and the data file is similar.

Comment: Have you run CHECKDB? What was its output? It seems to me using EMERGENCY mode and using DBCC CHECKDB to rebuild the log may help in bringing the database corruption free.

Comment: I am planning to run CHECKDB but just need to get authorization, will keep you posted thanks

Answer (score 1):

OS error 23 is "Data error (cyclic redundancy check)."
you can check those by running executing on the command prompt `net helpmsg 23`, this basically means that you have a serious error on your disk.

As the database is running what you need to to is to

- DONT PANIC
- Find your backups
- Script your replication setup
- Do a tail-of-the-log backup to have a restore point.
- Run `DBCC CHECKDB with NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS` and keep the output
- Turn of the SQL Server and copy the data and log files to a safe place -if possible
- Run CHKDSK on the log drive.
- Restart the SQL Server and run DBCC CHECKDB again if it comes out clean you should be able to restart the replication if not you will have to restore the database.

Comment: Really , you are suggesting to stop SQL Server. Well that would be a blunder

Comment: Yes - After making sure that there is useful backups in place and that checkdb repairs are not possible, Which is the likely scenario A CRC error  (cyclic redundnacy check)  means the filesystem is screwed at the block level and you will need to run chkdsk to see if that can be fixed.